# How to make my struct Identifiable? It has a unique numeric uid field

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, decodable, identifiable

In [a simple project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/FetchJsonEscapable/FetchJsonEscapable/ContentView.swift) I am trying to download a list of JSON objects:

```
struct TopResponse: Codable {
    let data: [Top]
}

struct Top: Codable /*, Identifiable */ {
    let uid: Int
    let elo: Int
    let given: String
    let photo: String?
    let motto: String?
    let avg_score: Double?
    let avg_time: String?
}
```

This works well and as the next step I would like to display it in a SwiftUI List and thus add `Identifiable` to the struct.

Unfortunately, this produces the compile error `Type 'Top' does not conform to protocol 'Identifiable'`:

[image: error 1]

By design of my backend app the field `uid` is a unique number.

So I am trying to fix the compile error by changing its type from `Int` to `ObjectIdentifier`, but the Swift compiler is still not happy with the new error `Type 'Top' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

[image: error 2]

What is happening here, is the compiler now maybe missing the `uid` field for decoding JSON? (and how could it possibly know that the incoming server data has such a field?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Identifiable` requires that your struct have an `id` property, it doesn't find the best suited one automatically.

If you want to use `uid` as the `id` property, implement it like this:

```
var id: Int { uid }
```